# Linked list of Linked List of Integers, Java.

Tags: java

I first ran into my problem trying to create a int[][] of very large size (7k by 30k) for a dictionary gap list postings program. But alas I run out of space trying to allocate the array. How might I create a 2-d array of integers?

What I want is a list of list in which each list in the list is a list of integers. Here is a sample of my code.

Code:

```
 static final int numberOfTerms = 6782;
 static final int numberOfLines = 30383;
 byte[][] countMatrix = new byte[numberOfLines][numberOfTerms];
 int[][] gapsMatrix = new int[numberOfLines][numberOfTerms]; // To big!!
```

This list of lists is going to be filled with integers that represent the gaps between two occurrences of the same word in a specific text. So in count matrix I hold a byte indicating whether a word is specified for a specified index. Then in the function I am creating right now I am going through the countMatrix and if I find a byte there, I take the current index minus the last found index and save that number in my 2D-array of integers which gives me the just the gaps between each of the same word in the text.

So how might I create a data structure I need to accomplish this?

Comment: Hey Dog I heard you like List of List so I answer with a List of Lists for your List needs! :P

Comment: Why are you mentioning linked lists in the title, while your question is really about arrays?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this will work for you but you can try [Sparse Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) as option if you want to stick to Array. There are several other options.`Map`, `List` ,`Weak reference Collections` etc

Answer (score 1):

To create an array you need to have enough memory to create it.

An `int` uses 4-bytes per values and an array uses at least N * M times that.

e.g. 4 * 30383 * 6782 is about 820 MB you need to have free to create this.

This is about $8 worth of memory so this should be a big problem unless you don't have this much or you set your maximum memory too low.

I would increase your maximum memory by 1 GB at least and it should work.

---

Alternatives include

- use a smaller size e.g. `char` or `short` or `byte` which is 2-4 x smaller.
- use off heap memory such as a memory mapped file.  This doesn't use much heap but does use disk space which is usually cheaper.
- increase your maximum memory size.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have insufficient memory to do that.

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/array_memory_usage.shtml

Sorry I didn't make it clear but, it is unlikely that using another DS is going to change this.

Comment: I stated that in my question. But thanks for the reiteration. Why do you think that link made it better?

Answer (score 0):

> So how might I create a data structure I need to accomplish this?

If is understand correctly, then you want to record gaps between same terms.
Let us say, you have array of terms you need to analyze, then:

```
    String[] terms = ...;
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<String, <Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
      String term = terms[i];
      List<Integer> positions = map.get(term);
      if (gaps == null) {
        positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      }
      positions.add(i);
      map.set(term, positions);
    }
```

Later you just look at the positions of each term and may calculate gaps between those. (You may integrate that gaps calculation into this code, but I leave it as exercise for you).